# How to clear cells-A:2 is on a sheet(Incdt) that is linked to A:2(Resident) on another sheet. Want to clear B2:F2 on (Incdt) when Resident is modified

Tags: google-sheets

//This code works if I edit the sheet but does not work if the link sheet is modified.I think it is because the cell that is being modified is the cell from another sheet that is linked to the sheet where I want the cells to be deleted.

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() == 'A1' && 
      e.range.getSheet().getName() == 'Incdt/Obs Rpt'
    ) 
    e.source.getRange('B1').clear()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a spreadsheet containing two sheets: `Incdt/Obs Rpt` and `Resident List`. Data on `Resident List` is being updated daily. Data on `Incdt/Obs Rpt` is linked to cells/values on `Resident List`, specifically:

- Cell A2 on `Incdt/Obs Rpt` is linked to Cell A2 on `Resident List`.

When cell A2 on `Resident List` is modified or changed, you want to clear the range B2:F2 on `Incdt/Obs Rpt`. Your script is designed to do this, but you are unsure what/where to modify in the script.

---

```
function onEdit(e){

  // create variables
  var sheet2monitor = "Resident List";
  var cell2monitor = "A2"
  var reportsheetname = "Incdt/Obs Rpt";
  var range2clear = "B2:F2"
  var source = e.source;
  var sheet = source.getSheetByName(reportsheetname);

  if(e.range.getA1Notation() == cell2monitor && e.range.getSheet().getName() == sheet2monitor) {
    // if is successful, do stuff
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: if is successful")
    sheet.getRange(range2clear).clear()
    
  }
  else{
    // if is not successful, do nothing
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: if is not successful");

  }
}
```

---

I created several variables that will enable you to easily modify ranges or sheet names if the need arises.

There are a couple of key differences to your draft script:

- the cell that is being monitored for a change is `A2` on sheet = `Resident List`
- the range to be cleared is `B2:F2` on sheet=`Incdt/Obs Rpt`